# Highlight empty column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to highlight all the cells of an empty column with conditional formatting, but while applying `=isblank($x2)` or `=$x2=""` on `=$x:$x` results in the column highlighted, entering data in a cell only causes the cell above to lose the background color.

`isblank()` only seems to accept a single cell as argument. 
Is there a function / formula that becomes true if all cells in a column are blank/empty?

(row 1 of the sheet contains fixed header cells.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(x:x;"<>")=1
```

should give you TRUE iff the column is empty but for the header

Edit : removed the dollars in my formula as was suggested in the comments, this fits better the initial question.

Comment: Works for me if I use "*" as search string. Do I need to add a rule for each column I want this in or can the test range be generalized?

Comment: No, just remove the dollar signs from the formula so the cell range can get adjusted to whatever range it is applied on..